# Printing the contents of a double linked list

Tags: c#, node.js, doubly-linked-list

I have a double linked list that I want to print using `Console.WriteLine()`. The problem I have is that I know how to print a list with just a Next node in terms of the stopping condition (which is when node.next is null), but this is a double linked list with both Next and Previous, where every node in the list connects to another node so there is no case where `node.next == null` is True.

What is the stopping condition in this type of list? Right now i have an infinite loop that printing the list over and over.

Comment: Doubly linked list doesn't mean there wouldn't be an end to it. Circular list wouldn't have an end. Which one do you have? And for circular you stop when you get to the first one you started with.

Comment: A doubly-linked list definitely has an end - the item where `Next` is `null`.

Comment: Even if you are calling it doubly linked but it is circular, you can still track at which item you started printing. Once you get to that item, that means you have printed everything.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen 
  Ok i understand now the difference between the two. what i build is a circular list that the end node connect's to the first node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation you gave is about `CircularLinkedList`.

And `next` of last element in `DoublyLinkedList` should have have 'null'.

Now if your question is about `CircularLinkedList` you should have an end pointer
than print till `tmp.next` reaches `end` pointer.

**UPDATE 1**

Generally this should be the printing logic for `CircularLinkedList`

```
public void PrintAll()
{
    Node<T> tmp = start;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tmp.data.ToString());
        tmp = tmp.next;
    } while (tmp != end.next);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i understand my mistake and i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate the double linked list in 1 direction (e.g: always next, or always previous) there should be a finite iteration.

If you still have an infinite iteration it means you have a cycle in the list. A cycle can be obtained by making the same node the "next" or "previous" of 2 or more nodes in the same linked list.

Answer (score 0):

In a circular list there is still a "beginning", which is also the "end" of it. So you start printing from node A and you print until the node's next pointer points to A.

Comment: Thank you, i understand my mistake and i fixed it like you said

Answer (score 0):

If you have a circular linked list, you should save the reference to the first node of your list before you start your iteration and the next time that you are passing over it, just compare the current cursor node with that reference and if they are equal(that should be true on that case), then that is your stop condition